# How to add symbol near variable in fwrite

Tags: php

Ok, it might sound stupid, but I don't know to add any symbol near variable for example I have variable: $animal = cat; the plural would be cats, i don't want to create new variable, but instead just add 's' letter in fwrite function.

```
fwrite($fh, "Hello, $string.'s');
```

I tried \n / \ etc. but probably there something different for this situation ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
"Hello, {$string}s"
```

The PHP manual has [a section explaining this](http://php.net/manual/en/language.types.string.php#language.types.string.parsing.complex). Please read it.